# How do I make use of Marquee in html?

Tags: html

I am new to html and I would like to know how to use Marquee. I would like the text to move right to left and left to right in alternating fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a marquee tag(if it's implemented on the browser), or do it with Dynamic HTML(javascript/variants + CSS).

In all honesty, marquees are evil because they distract the attention of the user from the content to a text, and this should only be implemented for practice purposes, and nothing more.

Comment: I really like the [W3C wiki entry](http://www.w3.org/wiki/index.php?title=HTML/Elements/marquee&oldid=52898): *"Examples: No, really. don't use it."*

Answer (score 3):

left below code in your html file

```
  <marquee direction="left">
        Your  text 
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a scrolling marquee (i.e. scrolling text or scrolling images) by using the `<marquee>` tag. You can make the text/images scroll from right to left, left to right, top to bottom, or bottom to top - it's your choice! Moreover, you can also create cool falling text effects using it.

A Marquee scrolling to left can be created as below:

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">
        Your slide-in text goes here
</marquee>
```

More information on [this link](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features: *"Elements in the following list are entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors: [...] `marquee`"*.

Comment: @Zeta: i am aware of it. OP only wants to know how he can use it.

Comment: @Zeta Have a look once again please...